# STS - Scala project not showing up

Tags: java, scala, eclipse-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, scala-ide

I have installed Scala IDE plugins from Eclipse Marketplace but there is no option to create Scala project.

NOTE:

I am using spring-tool-suite-3.6.2.RELEASE-e4.4.1
Installed Scala IDE for Eclipse & Scala Worksheet since JDT Weaving is already installed in STS.
Scala version: 2.11.2

Answer (score 0):

Create a regular project then when you right click on it in the package explorer there should be a Scala sub menu and you can "add Scala nature".  Now STS knows it's a Scala project.

Comment: I've created Java project and right clicked on it but no sub menu found.